# Android 'Inappbrowser does not support cordova api calls' error

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

Have an error in my cordova app

```
Inappbrowser does not support cordova api calls
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message says, the InappBrowser cannot make calls to the underlying Cordova APIs. What are you exactly trying to do in your case?

The InAppBrowser documentation states the following.

> The InAppBrowser window behaves like a standard web browser, and can't
>   access Cordova APIs. For this reason, the InAppBrowser is recommended
>   if you need to load third-party (untrusted) content, instead of
>   loading that into the main Cordova webview. The InAppBrowser is not
>   subject to the whitelist, nor is opening links in the system browser.

Here is the documentation link
[InAppBrowser Documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)